# Is there a way to create a Schema object using an XML schema consisting of circular dependencies?

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I've been given a schema that contains two .xsd files that include each other (a.xsd includes b.xsd, b.xsd includes a.xsd).  When I run them through my code to return a Schema object, I get an out of memory exception.

My code is as follows:

```
protected Schema createSchema(String fileName) throws Exception  {
  SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
  factory.setResourceResolver(resourceResolver);
  Resource schemaResource = resourceLoader.getResource(fileName);
  StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(schemaResource.getInputStream());
  Schema schema = factory.newSchema(streamSource);
  return schema;
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, factory.newSchema(streamSource) is using the includes, along with imports, to load the sources into memory.  And since these two xsd's include each other, they are loaded over and over again, filling up memory space.  Is there a way to break out of this loop and load the rest of the schema WITHOUT changing the schema design?

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that most schema processors could handle circular includes: they are never necessary, but they should be harmless. (However, the spec is far from clear on this point.)

Since you are using a resourceResolver of some kind, it's possible that the schema processor isn't recognizing that the URI of an include points back to a document it has already seen.

On the other hand, using a resourceResolver might be a way to eliminate the circularities by returning nothing (or an empty xs:schema) when a schema document is visited the second and subsequent times.

You don't actually say which schema processor you are using: there are at least two processors that implement the JAXP API which you are using here - more than that if you count different forks of Xerces.